Ubuntu detects wrong graphics card
I put in the graphics card from my old PC (GTX 1060) into my old DELL PowerEdge.
But it falsly detects a GTX 1050 card:
  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:fc80(size=128) memory:edf00000-edf7ffff

I know for sure that it is an 1060, which also is documented in the Product Specifications of my old PC (https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06276271)

You've provided no OS/release details which are critical to understanding what you're running, but the command you appear to be providing as paste details mostly provides strings of text the card provides itself... ie. how your card is reporting itself to the OS as... your issue appears to be card related.

I once wasted days on a "wrong device" until I noticed the label had been glued on after having been lifted off another device.  I would believe what your system is telling you, unless you have ever had a report that the GPU was a 1060.

nvm, they're not listed the same.

What does the output of lspci -nn -v | grep -A 5 'VGA ' | grep "VGA\|Subsystem" return?
